# Im getting error in Razorpay Payment Gatway

Tags: reactjs, mern, razorpay

while from backend it return   **success: true**                                                                             Object
studentFeaturesAPI.js:68 PAYMENT RESPONSE FROM BACKEND............ Objectdata: {id: 'order_MwhlzYLtfHmvnc', entity: 'order', amount: 100, amount_paid: 0, amount_due: 100, …}
**success: true**[[Prototype]]: Objectconstructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()**defineGetter**: ƒ **defineGetter**()**defineSetter**: ƒ **defineSetter**()**lookupGetter**: ƒ **lookupGetter**()**lookupSetter**: ƒ **lookupSetter**()**proto**: (...)get **proto**: ƒ **proto**()set **proto**: ƒ **proto**()

but frontend it show while opening paymentGateway whie clicking Buy Now it show this 400
(Bad Request)
first error                                                                                                            {
"error": {
"code": "SERVER_ERROR",
"description": "We are facing some trouble completing your request at the moment. Please try again shortly.",
"source": "NA",
"step": "NA",
"reason": "NA",
"metadata": {}
}
}

Any solution regrading this